# how to restrict file upload or drag and drop for pdf files only using angular13 without any 3rd party tools or plugins

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

i am using Angular13 and here i need to restrict file upload for pdf files only, for browse i was able to handle by using `accept=".pdf"` but not able to restrict for drag and drop files, i have used directive for that.

HTML:

Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appDragDrop]'
  })
  export class DragDirective {
    @Output() onFileDropped = new EventEmitter<any>();

    //Dragover listener
    @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(evt:any) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
    //Dragleave listener
    @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt:any) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
    //Drop listener
    @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt:any) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
      if (files.length > 0) {
        this.onFileDropped.emit(files)
      }
  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drop events will contain `event.dataTransfer` arguments. That's where you handle mime types.

Each `file` in `event.dataTransfer.files` you can access their `type`.

Comment: thanks for response, so "evt.dataTransfer.files" we need to check which type it is and then allow?

Comment: Yes, `evt.dataTransfer.files` is an array, you can check the `file.type` of each array item.